# How do I pass a url as string in url string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want link to send as parameter as query string, but the controller does not accept it, what's  wrong?

```
  function sendLink(){

    var link="http://xyz/1/1"

    var url="/abc/"+link;

     $.get(url,function(data){
              alert(data);
            });

    }
```

Comment: You don't use `link`? and wath is `pathname`?

Comment: 1. What is `pathname` ? 2. What kind of url accepts your `controller` ?

Comment: No the link is /abc/{link} I want the to paas link as string and want to get the link value in controller

Comment: When you say, controller, are you referring to the Microsoft MVC controller?

Comment: add your controller code you that will accept the link value

Comment: sorry its link in place of pathname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to put it on the query string:

```
var url="/abc/?pathname="+encodeURIComponent(pathname);
```

Then access it in your controller as the HTTP GET variable `pathname`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
function sendLink() {
    var link = "http://xyz/1/1";
    var url = "/abc/" + encodeURIComponent(link);

    $.get(url, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```